# What proper technique for MAUI to use API for Login

Tags: authentication, identity, maui-blazor, minimal-apis

I have a Blazor Server web application that uses Identity(DbContext, ApplicationUser) to login and register users.
I am creating a .Net Core 7.0 Web API to handle the login and database interactions for a MAUI Blazor hybrid mobile app that will use the same SQL database and Identity login.
The API is hosted on Azure App Service.

## My question is how do I make the MAUI app secure and use Identity and the api to login?

This is the API Code. This is a minimal API and does not use controllers

```
public static async Task<IResult> LoginUser(UserLoginModel user, SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager)
{
    if (signInManager != null)
    {
        try
        {
            var result = await signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(user.Email, user.Password, user.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: true);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                return Results.Ok(result);
            }

            if (result.IsLockedOut)
            {
                return Results.Unauthorized();
            }
            else
            {
                return Results.Problem("Invalid Login");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Results.Problem(ex.Message);
        }
    }
    else
        return Results.Problem("sign in is null");
}
```

This is the API endpoint

```
    app.MapPost(pattern: "Users/Login/{userloginnmodel}", 
    Login.LoginUser);
```

UserLoginModel is a simple email password and rememberme

```
    public class UserLoginModel
    {
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public bool RememberMe { get; set; }
    }
```

Swagger test passes if I enter login and password. The API returns Success is valid login.

Next..here is the login for the MAUI app

```
public class UserData : IUserData
    {
        public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Login(UserLoginModel userloginmodel)
        {
            try
            {
                using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
                {
                    using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("POST"), "https://..../Users/Login/{userloginmodel}"))
                    {
                        request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("accept", "*/*");  
                        request.Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(userloginmodel), Encoding.UTF8);
                        request.Content.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/json");
                        var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
                        return response;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
            }
        }
    }
```

The MAUI mobile app return a InternalServerError when I try to login from the app. Please note that the other endpoints work ok with the MAUI app and only the login is giving the error

Comment: Good question....I need to ask similar question for our Blazor hosted PWA solution.  Also.  The Blazor web-app is for the office personnel and the Maui+Blazor-app (for cell-phones) is for the vehicle drivers.  The SQL-Server DB holds the business data available to both the Maui-app and the office-app, including the identity data.  Thanks for asking your question.